# Can OptaPlanner be used for project schedule optimization (MS-Project style)?

Tags: java, optaplanner

Assuming a project schedule model with tasks (with start/end dates), and dependencies of type FS, FF, SS, SF, can OptaPlanner be used for project schedule optimization?
e.g. when the date of the schedule start task changes, use OptaPlanner to re-calculate the dates of all its successor tasks based on their dependency type. Similar to MS-Project auto scheduling functionality.
The OptaPlanner "project job scheduling" example seems the most relevant but it doesn't consider different successor dependency types. Also the example initial data structure is not clear.
Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes.**

---

Longer answer:

The project job scheduling example is arguably our most convoluted example. We'll soon build a simpler job shop scheduling quickstart.

As for the "consider different successor dependency types" constraint, please spec it out clearly in a separate question.

Comment: Thanks Geoffrey. Successor dependency 4 types (FS, FF, SS, SF) are following the concept used in MS-Project and Oracle Primavera as described here https://www.eastwoodharris.com/understanding-constraints-and-relationships-in-primavera-p6-8-2/

Comment: It would be nice to be able to export from MS Project (MSP) to OptaPlanner, use some includes for constraints and score calculation MSP is unable and back to MSP after solving. Unfortunately, in lots of companies, MSP is the standard.